# How to redirect to an other form after submiting in Bonita BPM

Tags: business-process-management, bonita, bpmn.io

Im working with bonita soft and i want know how to redirect to another form after sumiting the first form, what i have do write as a link on the submit button instead of the default */bonita*

[SreenShot in the UI designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hECIL.png)

Answer (score 1):

A button with the `action` configured to "Start process" as a property `Target URL on success`. This define the URL to load if the call to the Bonita Engine REST API to instantiate the process is successful (i.e. return HTTP code 200).

**Important:** this configuration will only be used if:

- the button is part of a `page` (as opposite to a `form`)
- if the instantiation form is loaded outside Bonita Portal (e.g. URL likes http://localhost:8080/bonita/portal/resource/process/MyProccessName/3.1.0/content/?id=7456900044110166462&locale=en&mode=app). This is the way an instantiation form is loaded when you click on the "run" button of Bonita Studio.

If the instantiation form is open from Bonita Portal "processes" menu and a click on the ▶ button this settings will be ignored. Submitting the form will get you back to the process definitions list.

The default value of `Target URL on success` property is "/bonita" meaning that after a user click on the button he will be redirected to the Bonita Portal main page (i.e. the task list).

If you want to redirect the user to another page you can use any valid URL to define the value of the `Target URL on success` property. Note that you can only use a static (constant) value for this property.

When the user submit the instantiation form from the Bonita Portal, the redirection to the process definitions list is hard coded in Bonita and cannot be changed as long as you are using the standard button widget.

So if you want to customize this behavior my recommendation would be to create a [custom widget](https://documentation.bonitasoft.com/bonita/7.8/custom-widgets) that will perform the [REST API](https://documentation.bonitasoft.com/bonita/7.8/rest-api-overview) call to [instantiate the process](https://documentation.bonitasoft.com/bonita/7.8/bpm-api) and update the parent frame location to the appropriate URL.